# type '()' cannot be derefernced

Tags: rust, hashmap

Could someone explain me why does it say that `*profession` is a unit type while it is a vector?

```rust
use hashbrown::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut sphere: HashMap<String, Vec<&str>> = HashMap::new();
    sphere.insert(String::from("junior"), vec![]);
    sphere.insert(String::from("Middle"), vec![]);
    sphere.insert(String::from("Senior"), vec![]);
    loop {
        println!();
        let mut input = String::new();
        std::io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut input)
            .expect("What the hell this doesn't work!?");
        if input.trim() == "stop" {
            break;
        }
        let splited_data: Vec<&str> = input.split(" to ").collect();
        let person = splited_data[0];
        let category = splited_data[1].to_string();
        let professions = sphere.entry(category.to_string()).or_insert(vec![]);
        *professions.push(person);
    }
}
```

```
error[E0614]: type `()` cannot be dereferenced
  --> src/lib.rs:21:9
   |
21 |         *professions.push(person);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Comment: Is the star operator correct there?

Comment: @thebusybee no. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6b41d00e72193a0e9aa5dfdecffe28e0

Comment: So that's the error.

Answer (score 9):

The `*` dereference operator has lower precedence than `.`, so this:

```
*professions.push(person);
```

is equivalent to:

```
*(professions.push(person));
```

The error you are seeing is because `Vec::push` returns `()`.

What you really want is to dereference the vector and then call `push`:

```
(*professions).push(person);
```

But Rust's [auto-deref rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/2018-edition/ch15-02-deref.html?highlight=deref%20auto#implicit-deref-coercions-with-functions-and-methods) make the the explicit dereference unnecessary and you can just write:

```
professions.push(person);
```

---

See also: [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules)